# Get Azure consumption and reservation usage data using API Unable to authenticate

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I am trying to authenticate this API.

Document link :

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/charge-back-usage#get-azure-consumption-and-reservation-usage-data-using-api
```

API_1: `https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{enrollmentId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/{billingPeriodId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usagedetails?metric={metric}&amp;api-version=2019-05-01&amp;$filter={filter}`

But I am getting this error:

```
{'error': {'code': '401', 'message': 'No claims present for the caller in the system'}}
```

But when I am trying to access this API:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2021-10-01&metric=amortizedcost
```

I am able to access using same credentials(SPN) .

above API documentation :

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list#usagedetailslistbymetricamortizedcost-legacy
```

Can anyone help me why I am unable to authenticate API_1 using same SPN.

using this code.

```
authentication_endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
resource  = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'

# get an Azure access token using the adal library
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authentication_endpoint + tenant_id)
token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, application_id, application_secret)
endpoint = "API_Link1"

access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
json_output = requests.get(endpoint,headers=headers).json()
print(json_output)
```

Can anyone help me what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment** and I am able to access the second API you have given:

[image: image1]

But for the first API error: **`python {'error': {'code': '401', 'message': 'No claims present for the caller in the system'}}`**  I believe that the reason is role claims are missing in the access token.

The **`roles`** are only issued in the access token when we request it using the [**client credentials flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which contains the permission that require admin consent.

I guess you need to check the **required permissions** granted on your SPN to access the API.

Comment: are you getting any information in meterdetails or it is null for all .can you please tell me what  kind of role needed to be assigned to authenticate API

Comment: try this api this one is not working for me https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{enrollmentId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/{billingPeriodId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usagedetails?metric={metric}&amp;api-version=2019-05-01&amp;$filter={filter}

Answer (score 0):

To get data at enrollment level or billing account level you need to billing reader role in you service principle.